# Can i use variable color variable with less css

Tags: css, variables, colors, less

Is there a way to declare the following:

```
body.someclass { @maincolor:#somecolor;}
bidy.anotherclass { @maincolor:#anothercolor;}
```

also tried:

```
 body.someclass {.maincolor {color:#somecolor;} }
 body.anotherclass {.maincolor {color:#anothercolor;} }
```

I'm working on a website where each of there mainsections uses a different color... would be extremely helpfull :)

Comment: Have you looked at the examples in the documentation?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You want variable property names?

Answer (score 0):

This code should work.

```
@color: #4D926F;
@color2: #000000;

body.someclass {
  color: @color;
}

body.anotherclass {
  color: @color2;
}
```

Comment: thx for the quick reply... however, this way, all elements (body, p, h1 > ..., ... ) are assigned with color:#4D926F.

Comment: : ) different color... still all elements

Comment: @KoenBulens: You probably need to update your question and be more clear what you are after. Any `color` setting to the `body` element is going to inherit to "all elements" that do not set there own `color` simply by CSS rules (regardless of LESS). So what are you trying to achieve by setting `color` on the `body` element that is different from what Doink has offerred here?